# Convert Text into Hyperlinks <a> and Image tags <img>

Tags: javascript

I am using this function to convert text into clickable links (`<a href=""> </a>`) and image urls into img tags (`<img src="" />`).

```js
const parsecontent = (text)=>{
    var ishyperlink= /([^\S]|^)((https?\:\/\/)(\S+))/gi;
    return (text || "").replace(ishyperlink,
    function(match, space, url){
       var isimglink = /https?:\/\/.*\.(?:png|jpg|gif|jpeg)/i;
        if (url.match(isimglink)) {
         return space + '<a href="' + url + '"><img src="' + url + '" /></a>';
        }
     return space + '<a href="' + url + '">' + url + '</a>';
    }
  );
}
```

Using like this

```js
const div = document.querySelector("#content");
div.innerHTML = parsecontent(div.innerHTML);
```

It works fine, if the content with proper spaces. It links, image urls not separated with spaces it fails. Can you pls help me to fix this?

Codepen here https://codepen.io/dagalti/pen/GRqpYLp

[image: screen]

Comment: if i understand just remove the second `^` from ([^\S]|^). And with joined links is problem. You can add end with .com but this is not good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a regex that's tailored to satisfy your test cases.

This regex is how we will match for a URL:

```regex
((https?\:\/\/)([\w!"#$%&\'()*+,-./@:;=\^_`{|}~]*))
```

In your example, we have 2 urls together with no whitespace in between. What happens if we have a url and a non-url string with no whitespace between? We *could* terminate the match when it reaches a TLD (such as `.com`, `.org`, etc). To satisfy your example however, I am making the assumption that we are dealing with 2 urls separated by no whitespace. In that case, we want to terminate the match when we notice the start of a new url `(?=https?)`:

```regex
([^\S]|^)((https?\:\/\/)([\w!"#$%&\'()*+,-./@:;=\^_`{|}~]*))(?=https?)
```

Next we want to match the urls that are surrounded by whitespace:

```regex
((https?\:\/\/)([\w!"#$%&\'()*+,-./@:;=\^_`{|}~]*))
```

Putting all this together we get this regex:

```regex
([^\S]|^)((https?\:\/\/)([\w!"#$%&\'()*+,-./@:;=\^_`{|}~]*))(?=https?)|((https?\:\/\/)([\w!"#$%&\'()*+,-./@:;=\^_`{|}~]*))
```

We have to adjust your `replace` logic a bit too:

```js
const parsecontent = (text)=>{
    var ishyperlink= /([^\S]|^)((https?\:\/\/)([\w!"#$%&\'()*+,-./@:;=\^_`{|}~]*))(?=https?)|((https?\:\/\/)([\w!"#$%&\'()*+,-./@:;=\^_`{|}~]*))/gi;
    return (text || "").replace(ishyperlink,
    function(url){
       var isimglink = /https?:\/\/.*\.(?:png|jpg|gif|jpeg)/i;
        if (url.match(isimglink)) {
         return '<a href="' + url + '"><img src="' + url + '" /></a>';
        }
     return '<a href="' + url + '">' + url + '</a>';
    }
  );
}
```

This regex is quite verbose, there may be more succinct ways of satisfying your test cases (I'm not a *regexpert* though)

Comment: Thaks for your answer. but its not working. This change makes whole text hyperlinked. pls test with codepen https://codepen.io/dagalti/pen/GRqpYLp

Comment: Take a look at my updated answer. There are a number of ways for us to match urls such as matching TLDs, but I am making the assumption that we are only dealing with links that aren't separated by whitespace.

Comment: Thank you. Working now. before this  replaced all 'http' with ' http' then regex.